# Perform a task after UIAlertView dismissed

Tags: ios, uialertview

I have a `UIlertView` to ask user if he/she wants to backup data before performing something with the data. I did something like this to capture if user tapped on Yes:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    if (buttonIndex != alertView.cancelButtonIndex)
        [self backupData];

    [self doSomethingWithData];
}
```

But when the user dismisses the `UIAlertView` the UI will froze until the `backupData` and `doSomethingWithData` methods complete. I think performing those methods in background is not acceptable since `doSomethingWithData` has to be started when `backupData` is finished.
How can I dismiss the UIAlertView completely, then start `backupData` or `doSomethingWithData` methods?

Comment: Do your long running actions in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the solution is easy:

You **don't want freeze the UI** ---> **Use background** execution with dispatcher;

You **want execute something after the backup** ---> **Pass a block** for the completion.

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex != alertView.cancelButtonIndex){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^
        {
            __weak typeof (self) weakSelf = self;
            [self backupDataWithCompletion:^(NSData *data) {
                [weakSelf doSomethingWithData:data];
            }];
        });

    }
}

- (void)backupDataWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSData *))completionBlock 
{
    NSData *data = //Do something

    completionBlock(data);
}
```

Or another solution (less elegant) is to insert the tasks in a SERIAL QUEUE that doesn't work on the main thread:

So init this queue in your `init` method:

```
_queue = dispatch_queue_create("backupQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
```

queue is a property or var `dispatch_queue_t queue;`
Then:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex != alertView.cancelButtonIndex){

        dispatch_async(queue, ^
        {
            [self backupData];
        });

        dispatch_async(queue, ^
        {
            [self doSomethingWithData];
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you use `weakSelf` for the second method and not just `self`?

Comment: To avoid retain cycle

Comment: The first method didn't work for me. `doSomethingWithData` method is not getting called.

Comment: Which part of code do you mean? I copied the code you've provided and renamed the methods. But second method is not getting called. I put a breakpoint at the beginning

Comment: Did you edit your code to work and call the completion block?

Comment: Pleasure. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Just execute these methods in the background. You are most likely doing some heavy stuff on the main thread, blocking the UI.

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^
    {
        //code in background
    });
}
```

Alternatively, you can run one method in the background and call second one on the main thread when the first one finishes using code below.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^
{
    // do your background tasks here
    [self doSomethingInBackground];

    // when that method finishes you can run whatever you need to on the main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        [self doSomethingInMainThread];
    });
});
```

Comment: When run [self doSomethingInBackground] in the background, why would the App wait until it finished then goes to [self doSomethingInMainThread]?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(doSomethingWithData) withObject:nil afterDelay:.1];
```

in your variant it will be called in the main thread.

**OR**

you can also use the code below to move it to the background thread

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doSomethingWithData) withObject:nil];
```

**OR**

you can use lots of suggestions with dispatches, the result will be the same...